# Overload capslock with esc and ctrl using xcape

Tags: xmodmap

I want to:

1. Turn off `capslock` when hitting the `capslock key`
2. `Escape` when hitting the `capslock key`
3. Behave like `ctrl` when pressing down the `capslock key`

What I have in my `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
!Set Capslock to LCtrl
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keycode 66 = Control_L
add Control = Control_L

!Set Escape to Capslock
keycode 9 = Caps_Lock
add Lock = Caps_Lock

!Dummy Escape Key for XCape
keycode 254 = Escape
```

What I have at the end of my `~/.profile`:

```
$HOME/xcape/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape' # Run xcape after login
```

Things work mostly as expected with just `Xmodmap`, and mostly as expected with `Xmodmap` + `$HOME/xcape/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'` when not run from `.profile`.

I get some strange behaviors when it runs from `.profile`; `capslock key` still toggles `capslock` in addition to behaving as `esc` and `ctrl`. My `left ctrl` exhibits this exact behavior as well.

Maybe I should be running this from somewhere other than `.profile`?

Edit: tried running `$HOME/xcape/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'` from xubuntu's menu -> settings manager -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart with no effect at all.

Comment: If anyone is wondering about use case, I use a vim emulator in emacs and it's convenient to have the capslock key behave as both esc and ctrl. It all works well enough with the slight off-behavior of the ctrl key also behaving as esc and having to run the xcape command every time I restart.

Comment: you don't have to run it manually on startup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Answer (score 1):

`.Xmodmap`:

```
clear lock
clear control
keycode 66 = Control_L
add control = Control_L Control_R
```

Under Settings > Session and Startup > Application Autostart > Add:

```
/path/to/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'
```

This works with the side effect of LCtrl also escaping when tapped. Not perfect but hasn't bothered me enough to fix it in the years I've used it.